# Inserting meta tags into the <head> . . .</head> area created by get_header()

Tags: wordpress

I've written a custom template to generate a page from database fields.  At the top I have a  `get_header()`, which generates the page `DOCTYPE`, opening `<html>`, opening and closing `<head> . . .</head>`, and opening `<body>`.  A `get_footer()` 
I placed at the end closes the open `<html>` with a `</html>`  and closes the open `<body>` with a `</body>`.

Now I'd like to add a meta tag in the header, something like

```
<meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

What is the best way to insert this into the `<head> . . .</head>` that `get_header()` creates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into `wp_head` before the `get_header()`.

```
function my_hook_header() {
 echo '<meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />';
}
add_action('wp_head','my_hook_header');
```

Comment: Ok, that looks good.  Just curious, though, if this goes before the get_header() how does it end up after the <head> that get_header() creates?